# Строчные элементы во flexbox'ах

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Возможно странный вопрос но почему строчным элементам воженным в блок с `display:flex` можно задавать размеры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ построения страниц через flexbox не связан с традиционным способом построения CSS. Любой элемент который выступает в роли дочернего flex-контейнера не подчиняется стандартным правилам CSS и поэтому совершенно не важно каким он является в CSS, во flex они все будут блочными. Единственное исключение, что по некоторым правилам элементы могут выпадать из построения flex-макета и возвращаться к традиционному способу построения.

Answer (score 2):

Все просто, у первых потомков элемента с `display:flex` переопределяется свойство `display:block`(теперь ему можно задавать размер в отличии от `display:inline`), вот так:

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('span1')).display)
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('span2')).display)
```

```css
.wrap{display:flex}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><span id="span1">span1</span></div>
<span id="span2">span2</span>
```