# Какой тип отображения у flexbox элемента

Tags: html, css

Как мы знаем в основном html-теги поделены на несколько типов отображения, часто используемые это inline и block.

Но какой тип отображения будут иметь элементы flexbox контейнера?
Спрашиваю из того что block и inline элементы отображаются одинаково во flexbox контейнере.

```css
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
.flex-container > *{
  background-color:#0098ff;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid #0153a0;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div> <!-- block -->
  <span>2</span> <!-- inline -->
  <span>3</span> <!-- inline -->
  <div>4</div> <!-- block -->
  <div>5</div> <!-- block -->
  <div>6</div> <!-- block -->
  <span>7</span> <!-- inline -->
  <div>8</div> <!-- block -->
</section>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#flex-items

Comment: Сам посмотри `let chld = document.querySelector('.flex-container').children;
for (let i = 0; i < chld.length; i++){
console.log(getComputedStyle(chld[i])['display']);
}`

Comment: сам тип отображения не меняется, но child элементы подчинаются flex контейнеру

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856029/Строчные-элементы-во-flexboxах

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо за ссылку на спецификацию :) Там как раз говорится как воспринимаются элементы flexbox. И даже упоминается что они превращаются при такой разметке в режим отображения block.

Comment: @Air интересно, я бы удивился если бы спецификация явно не говорила об превращении всех элементов контейнера flexbox в block

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Строчные элементы во flexbox'ах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856029/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%be-flexbox%d0%b0%d1%85)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko сверху это упомянули к чему ваш дубликат?

Comment: @MaximPro чтобы закрыть ваш вопрос и система поставила ссылку на тот, в котором есть полноценные ответы, а не комментарии.